# Android In App Billing NullPointerException on Android 8.0

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I received complain from Android 8.0 users that after they have made the payment, my app crash. They are unable to receive the purchased item. My in app billing is using code from TrivialDrive (AIDL). It works well on other Android versions. This is the crash report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at .ConceptActivity$12.a (ConceptActivity.java:9)
  at .inappbilling.util.IabHelper$2$1.run (IabHelper.java:8)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:790)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6501)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:438)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

My `IabHelper` was called in `onCreate`.

```
String base64EncodedPublicKey = 
                                       "<license key here>";

            mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

            mHelper.startSetup(new 
            IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                 public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) 
             {
                       if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                         Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " + 
                    result);
                       } else {             
                         Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                   }
                     }
            });
```

This is the my Purchase Finished Listener:

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
            = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                          Purchase purchase)
        {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                checkItem();
                return;
            }
            else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
                removeAds();
            }

        }
    };
```

And my Query Inventory Finished:

```
public void checkItem() {
        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
    }

    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
            = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                             Inventory inventory) {

            if (mHelper == null) return;
            Purchase purchase = inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU);
            if (purchase != null) {
                removeAds();
            }
        }
    };
```